# Разделить long long на две части (Старшая - long) и (Младшая - unsigned long)

Tags: c++, типы-данных, битовые-операции

Догадываюсь, что провернуть данную операцию возможно с помощью побитового сдвига, но как - не совсем понимаю. Буду очень признателен, если найду ответ.

Пример того, как это должно работать в моём представлении.

```
std::pair<long,unsigned long> detach(const long long& _Value) {
    long high = _Value << 32;
    unsigned long low = _Value << 32;

    return std::pair<long,unsigned long>(high,low);
  }
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что в `long long` не обязательно ровно 64 бита. А даже если и 64, то в `long` может быть меньше.

Comment: А так, чтобы получить младшую часть нужно обнулить старшую с помощью побитового И.

Comment: @eanmos, можно с вами как-то связаться? Честно говоря, не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: `_Value & 0xFFFFFFFF`, большое число справа — это 32-битная битовая маска со всеми единичками.

Comment: Но я говорю, такое может работать, но лучше так не делать. Берите типы с фиксированной шириной —  `uint64_t` и ко.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При распространенном варианте - long long - 64 бита, long - 32 -

```
std::pair<long,unsigned long> detach(const long long& _Value) {

    long high = _Value >> 32;
    unsigned long low = _Value &0xFFFFFFFF;
    return std::pair<long,unsigned long>(high,low);
}
```

Варианты могут быть и другие, но это вряд ли - потому что, например, при равенстве long и long long по размеру сложно говорить о старшей и младшей части, правда? :)

Но в общем случае можно воспользоваться оператором `sizeof()`. Только как именно поступать в том или ином случае - это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: Ну тогда, наверное, немного ассертов можно накинуть, для надежности)